# bash adding 1 to variable in while loop

Tags: bash, shell

The situation is as following:
I have a .txt file that includes series of letters all divided bij newlines
Here's a small part of the file:

```
lrtjxz
lrtjhs
lrtsxv
lrtvsw
lrtywj
lrtyws
lrxwwv
lrvhsx
lryjts
lrytwv
lrzvwj
lzwscr
lzjrww
lzjroj
lzjrvs
lzjrhs
lzojvs
```

I created a script that would count the number of times one of these lines is alphabetically ordered. But for some reason it echo's nothing not even 0.

Script:

```
cat file.txt | while read line
do
alphabeticSorted=$(echo $line | grep -o . | sort)
if [ "$line" == "$alphabeticSorted" ]
then
count=$((count + 1))
fi
done

echo "$newCount"
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Unix SE, as the link to the possible duplicate question highlights, the trouble is with the pipe.  When you create a pipe the different parts end up in subshells, and a subshell cannot change the parent's variables.  You can rewrite that loop to avoid a pipe though by using input redirection

Comment: Note that the way the script is written right now `$alphabeticSorted` will never equal `$line` for input like "abcdef" due to the newlines inserted by `grep -o .`.

Comment: Your code could also be improved by removing the UUOC (Useless Use of Cat)

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two different issues, and both contribute to the outcome of no echo.

Here are the details:

### Bad comparison

You wrote:

```
alphabeticSorted=$(echo $line | grep -o . | sort)
if [ "$line" == "$alphabeticSorted" ]
```

- `grep -o` puts each match on its own per line
- `.` matches a single individual character
- the original line has characters horizontally
- but the `grep -o` places characters "vertically"
- so the original `$line` is never going to equal the after-grep line

For example, on command prompt you can test this:

```
$ line="abc"
```

Now see what the original `$line` contains:

```
$ echo "$line"
abc
```

Now see how `grep -o` changes it, and this is basically your `$alphabeticSorted`

```
$echo "$line" | grep -o .
a
b
c
```

So remember you wrote this:

```
if [ "$line" == "$alphabeticSorted" ]
```

So what Bash is actually testing is, does:

```
abc
```

equal to

```
a
b
c
```

Well as you can see it is not the same thing, so your `if` statement would never be true even if your original `$line` was perfectly alphabetical.

I would highly recommend making them both the same orientation, either both horizontal or both vertical. Let us do both horizontal, so you can test in Bash

```
$ line2=$( echo $line | grep -o . | sort | tr -d '\n'

$ echo $line2
abc
```

- we add `tr` command, the `-d` to delete something, and the something, being new lines `\n`
- thus the `$line2` is "horizontal" just like the `$line1`

So in your original code if you just modify it so

```
alphabeticSorted=$(echo $line | grep -o . | sort | tr -d '\n')

if [ "$line" == "$alphabeticSorted" ]
```

It should now be a more reasonable comparison.

### Wrong variable

But even if you fix this, there is a second problem with your posted script, which is you have this in the body of your code:

```
count=$((count + 1))
```

But you are not referring to `$count` at all, you said you wrote:

```
echo "$newCount"
```

Because there is no `$newCount` defined, of course when calling this, there is no value, it is nothing, so you get nothing. What you probably wanted was:

```
echo "$count"
```

So with those two bugs addressed, as far as I can tell from the code provided, it should now work.